# Logback logger name with wildcard

Tags: logging, logback

Is it possible to use a wildcard for the logger name which matches different packages so we don't have to specify them all individually? So instead of writing

```
<logger name="com.package1.web" level="debug"   
<logger name="com.package2.web" level="debug"  
<logger name="com.package3.web" level="debug"
```

I would like to only specify one entry somewhat like this:

```
<logger name="com.*.web" level="debug"
```

If anyone knows about a way or also just that it's not a possibility i'd highly appreciate it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with Filters in the appender. Basically you have to set up a logger for `com.*` with `DEBUG` level, and apply a filter which *DENIES* all `DEBUG` (or lower) events which are *NOT* `com.*.web`.

I admit that it is quite convoluted.

Performance-wise it is also poor: `DEBUG` events are created for **all** `com.*` events, and only at the appender they are thrown away or kept.

Anyway, example `logback.xml` file:

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
                <expression>
                    !(e.loggerName ==~ "com\\..*\\.web") &amp;&amp;
                    DEBUG.toInt() >= e.level.toInt()
                </expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%p [%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c - %m\n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Test code:

```
public void test() throws Exception{
    getLogger("com.package1.web").debug("some debug onto com.package1.web");
    getLogger("com.package2.web").debug("some debug onto com.package2.web");
    getLogger("com.package3.web").debug("some debug onto com.package3.web");
    getLogger("com.package1.web").info("some info onto com.package1.web");
    getLogger("com.package2.web").info("some info onto com.package2.web");
    getLogger("com.package3.web").info("some info onto com.package3.web");
    getLogger("com.package3.notweb").debug("some debug onto com.package3.notweb");
    getLogger("com.package3.notweb").info("some info onto com.package3.notweb");
}

public Logger getLogger(String loggerName) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
}
```

Result:

```
DEBUG [12:30:46] com.package1.web - some debug onto com.package1.web
DEBUG [12:30:46] com.package2.web - some debug onto com.package2.web
DEBUG [12:30:46] com.package3.web - some debug onto com.package3.web
INFO [12:30:46] com.package1.web - some info onto com.package1.web
INFO [12:30:46] com.package2.web - some info onto com.package2.web
INFO [12:30:46] com.package3.web - some info onto com.package3.web
INFO [12:30:46] com.package3.notweb - some info onto com.package3.notweb
```

as you can see, `DEBUG` logs are written only for `com.*.web`.

Answer (score 23):

### TL;DR

Logback does not support wildcards at intermediate levels in the logger name.

### Detail

Logback (implicitly) supports wildcards *at the end* of the logger name, so `<logger name="com.package1.web" ...>` effectively means:

- Classes in `com.package1.web` **and** in any sub packages of `com.package1.web`

Logback does this by creating a hierarchy of loggers; the logger for `com.package1.web` is parented by a logger for `com.package1` which is parented by a logger for `com` which is parent by the `ROOT` logger.

So, if you declare `<logger name="com.package1.web" level="debug">` and then attempt to emit a debug log message for a logger on `com.package1.web.foo.bar` Logback will walk up that logger's hierarchy until it finds a logger for which the `DEBUG` level is enabled, it will find this at `com.package1.web` and hence it will emit the DEBUG log event.

However, Logback will not create a hierarchy based on a wilcard at an intermediate level in the logger name. So, this ...

```
<logger name="com.*.web" level="debug">
```

... will not cause Logback to create loggers for:

- `com.package1.web`
- `com.package2.web`
- `com.package3.web`

Logback's hierarchy behaviour will not be applied when the wildcard is presented at an intermediate level in the logger name.

### Possible Solution

One benefit of this hierarchy behaviour is that it allows you to apply logger configuration to a package and all classes below that package i.e. it creates an *association* between logger instances based on their parentage. You *could* make this association by providing an explicit logger name, rather than defaulting it to the current class name.

For example:

```
<logger name="DEBUG_LOGGER" level="debug">
```

Then everywhere you want to use the debug logger just create a Logger instance like so:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DEBUG_LOGGER");
```

Clearly, there are drawback to this approach too, I'm just mentioning it here to show that there is another way (other than fully qualified class name) to associate logger instances and apply a level to them.