# Disable akka logging for akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, akka-cluster

I get bunch of messages like these:

```
2018-09-25 14:22:42.606 [DEBUG] akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://cluster) - Resolve (deserialization) of path [system/ddataReplicator/$b#1795511840] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
2018-09-25 14:22:42.607 [DEBUG] akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://cluster) - Resolve (deserialization) of path [system/ddataReplicator/$a#161990085] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
2018-09-25 14:22:48.897 [DEBUG] akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://cluster) - Resolve (deserialization) of path [system/ddataReplicator/$b#1795511840] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
2018-09-25 14:22:48.898 [DEBUG] akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://cluster) - Resolve (deserialization) of path [system/ddataReplicator/$a#161990085] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
```

which I would like not to log at debug level. Afaik I cannot just use logger name `akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider` because the full logger name includes cluster name (`akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://cluster)`), and we name those differently based on environment it is run, so something like this won't work:

```
<logger name="akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider" level="info" />
```

One option as I understand would be to use regex filters:

Which works, but I'm not sure if this is optimal?

Comment: just using the package is not an option? Like `<logger name="akka.actor" level="info" />`

Comment: no, that is too broad I am affraid...

Comment: I found an answer that maybe helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664150/2750966

Comment: filter is more advanced version of regex filter:) But as I said, not sure this is very optimal

Comment: Adding a logback.xml should take care.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding:

```
<logger name="akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://${sys:logging.clustername})" level="info" />
```

And then passing the `logging.clustername` at runtime with :

```
-Dlogging.clustername=current-cluster-name
```